# How to have different number of Column for users in a Table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

- I am new to postgres & databases. I am trying to make a *Password
  Manager*. I have one **table named password** where I store passwords and other table 'person' where I store their unique id and other details.
- now the problem in password table is that
  every user will have different number of passwords that they want to
  store. So I am not sure about the number of columns that I want this table to have.
- What I want to do is have a single row for every user and add all
  details in that row itself, and each user can have different number
  of passwords. However I am not able to figure out how to do that.
- **SO** I am thinking that since each user has a unique id , ,(*say user1 has id 2*) so I can add different rows with
  same id storing details. And would simply run `SELECT * FROM password where id=2`. So it will list all of the passwords stored by them and
  this works
- However I was wondering of a more efficient way to do this . So
  please help me out
- **IF you did'nt understood it** please go to [this link](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AhPoaAlnRK34hFGZUoI_jIGIKtFa?e=JYeYfX) I have described it better there.

Comment: This is the proper way to do it. A table with columns user_id and password and their combination to be unique.

Comment: @forpas Please See This [link](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AhPoaAlnRK34hFGZUoI_jIGIKtFa?e=JYeYfX), it show the problem better. Thank you for the help

Comment: It looks good although you don't need the column usename in the table password. The user's id is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right way regarding the idea of using a second table to store the various logins (website, website_username, password).
However you should make use of the concept of primary keys and foreign keys in a relational database here. For your example, this would mean:

You define the "id" column in your person table as primary key, and the "pid" column in your passwords table as a foreign key referencing the id in the person table. If I looked this up correctly, you use the REFERENCES keyword for this. See https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-foreign-key/ for example. You can (and should) also get rid of the username field in your "passwords" table, as this is redundant information.

Then you can query for your users and join these two tables via an INNER JOIN over the primary id and the foreign pid, see https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-inner-join/
Your query could then look something like this (I renamed your "password" table to "login" here for better readability:

```
SELECT person.id, username, website, website_username, password FROM person INNER JOIN login ON login.pid = person.id;
```

Then you have all your logins per user returned to you. Of course you can narrow it down by using the WHERE keyword as you did in your example query and the end of your document.

Although this is outside of the question’s scope: avoid storing passwords in plain text. Always hash them.

Hope this helped :)